# how to build a UNO Platform MacOS desktop app

Tags: macos, uno-platform

I am able to build a Uno Platform app on Droid, iOS, UWP and WASM, but when I try the macOS platform, I an unsuccessful with the following issues:
If I attempt to build on my Windows box using a Debug/x64 configuration, I get:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.Mac, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

If I attempt to build on my Mac-Mini, I get conflicting messages. From Build/Build All, the response is:

```
Building solution xxxx (Debug|x64)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skiped ====
Build successful.
```

the Mac was apparently successful building nothing.

If I just click on the run button, a message is displayed saying "**The application has not been built.**" The active configuration is set to: **Debug|x64**

I am really not sure what I am overlooking.  Since I'm unfamiliar with the mac environment I have the following questions:

1. What is the difference between a Uno ios and Uno mac application?
2. Is a Uno mac application, a Mac **desktop** application (similar to the UWP build), which is what I want?
3. On an Uno Mac platform build, should it be a debug|x64 or debug|iphoneSimulator?
4. What is the difference between an iOS build and a MacOS build using debug|iPhone simulator?

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to get a build.  What I am after is a MAC desktop app that **isn't constrained by device screen widths**.

Thanks for any insight with this problem.

Comment: For mac desktop, you don't want anything *iOS* (iPad and iPhone OS). The macintosh desktop operating system is called *macOS*.

Answer (score 0):

The Uno Platform macOS stack relies heavily on the Xamarin tooling for macOS, so I'd start by following the [Xamarin for macOS guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/) to make sure your environment is properly configured to build and run Xamarin.Mac applications. Also, for developing Uno Platform Mac apps, you need to run the project using Visual Studio for Mac. As for your questions:

> What is the difference between a Uno ios and Uno mac application?

From an Uno Platform perspective, the difference is that they both rely on different Xamarin tools for building apps, one is based in Xamarin.iOS and the other is based on Xamarin.Mac. More info [here](https://platform.uno/uno-platform-for-ios-and-android/) and [here](https://platform.uno/uno-platform-for-macos/).

> Is a Uno mac application, a Mac desktop application (similar to the UWP build), which is what I want?

Yes, the macOS head of an Uno Platform project generates a native Mac desktop binary, that can be run directly on your Mac and deployed to the Mac App Store as normal.

> On an Uno Mac platform build, should it be a debug|x64 or debug|iphoneSimulator?

As per the official Xamarin.Mac guide linked above, you should be using "Debug | My Mac" configuration.

> What is the difference between an iOS build and a MacOS build using debug|iPhone simulator?

The "iPhoneSimulator" configuration target is only valid for iOS apps being deployed to the simulator. This configuration has iOS-specific symbols, a Xamarin.Mac app will simply ignore those symbols and should run the app like if using the "Debug" configuration.